# API call returns image after I render the components

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, google-api, browserify

I'm using `g-s-i` a npm package to make calls to `google images`.

I'm unable to make this API call and, just after, render the application. I'm aware this has to do with `async`, but I have no idea how to use it here. I have tried many things with the function `imageSearch`, but nothing has worked.

I thank if someone can show me a solution to my problem.

My MWE:

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Debug example</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Debugger example</h1>
        <div id="main">
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="module" src="./dist/bundle.js">
    </script>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
var gis = require('g-i-s'); // search images from google https://www.npmjs.com/package/g-i-s

var main = document.querySelector("#main")

// Query examples
var searchTopics = [
  {
    searchTerm: 'sleep',
    queryStringAddition: '&tbs=ic:trans'
  },
  {
    searchTerm: 'pony',
    queryStringAddition: '&tbs=ic:trans',
    filterOutDomains: ['deviantart.net', 'deviantart.com']
  }
];

var imageSearch = (query) => {
  let response = [];
  gis(query, (error, results) => {
    console.log(results[1].url)
    response.push(results[1].url)
      }
  )
  return response;
};

// =results= look like:
// [
//   {
//     "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mW3S0u8bj58/maxresdefault.jpg",
//     "width": 1280,
//     "height": 720
//   },
//   {
//     "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tntOCGkgt98/maxresdefault.jpg",
//     "width": 1600,
//     "height": 1200
//   },
//   (...)
// ]


var imageLayout = (title) =>
    ((src) => {let e = document.createElement("div")
              e.innerHTML = title
              let img = document.createElement("img")
              img.src = src
              e.appendChild(img)
              return e})

var render = (queries) => {
  queries.forEach((query) =>{

    let img = imageSearch(query)
    console.log(img)

    main.appendChild(imageLayout(query.searchTerm)(img[0]))
  })}

render(searchTopics)
```

NPM:

```sh
npm init
npm install g-i-s

npm install --save-dev browserify @babel/core @babel/preset-env babelify

browserify js/main.js > ./dist/bundle.js -t babelify
watchify js/*.js -o ./dist/bundle.js -d
```

What happens in my browser:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `imageSearch` function calls `gis()` which doesn't successfully create the `response` object until the callback passed as the second parameter to `gis()` is called.  However, you're immediately returning the empty response array.

Instead, pass a callback in to `imageSearch` that gets called when `gis()` returns, something like this:

```js
const imageSearch = (query, cb) => {
  gis(query, (error, results) => cb(error, results[1].url));
};

const render = (queries) => {
  queries.forEach((query) => {
    let img = imageSearch(query, (error, img) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("An error happened: ", error);
        return;
      }

      main.appendChild(imageLayout(query.searchTerm)(img))
    });
  });
};
```

You could also move on to using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) but that's a different matter, and would not largely change the outcome of the code, just the format of it.

Comment: Thank you so much. That made a lot of sense. Although, I searched through uses of this package on GitHub, and saw both `Promises` and `callbacks` being used. I hadn't understood them so far. You were of great help . Thank you.